# How to compare one column array with another?

Tags: php

I have 2 SQLs: SQLa and SQLb. SQLa selects the latest 9 articles from the database. The other does the same but orders the articles by view count. So, I want the second SQL, that is, SQLb not to select articles that is selected in the first SQL (SQLa).

```
$sqla = "SELECT post_id, title, post_img, cnt FROM post ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 9;";
$sqlb = "SELECT post_id, title, post_img, cnt FROM post ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 9;";
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP? Why not do this purely in the database?

Comment: a `NOT IN` SQL query should allow you to do this all in one SQL statement, without needing PHP to assit

Comment: @ADyson that doesnt work. Because rows are array

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I was thinking something like `SELECT post_id, title, post_img, cnt FROM post WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM post ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 9) ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 9;`. Did you try that? What exactly was the result? "doesn't work" isn't really a useful description of any problem you might have. (obviously it would be easier for us to help if we could see your schema and some sample data. A [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) demo would be even better.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `WHERE post_id NOT IN (id,id,id,id)` you can exclude the earlier selected posts. To obtain those id's you have to loop the result of the first query and store the id's in an array.

- execute `$sqla` and store in `$result`.
- then loop `$result`:

  ```
  $not_in=[];
  foreach($result as $row){
     //do what you need to do with the values of query 1
     //...
     //store the id's in an array
     $not_in[]=$row['post_id'];
     }
  ```
- Now you can use them in your second query:

  ```
  $in = implode(',', $not_in); 
  $sqlb = "SELECT post_id, title, post_img, cnt 
         FROM post 
         WHERE post_id NOT IN ($in)
         ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 9;";
  ```